# Traer datos a un listado

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

quizas la pregunta que hare sea muy simple de resolver, pero en realidad no puedo obtener lo que necesito.  Tengo un listado que traigo desde la bbdd SQLSERVER. la cual hace el proceso que necesito, hasta ahi todo bien, empiezo a armar mi tabla sin problemas, pero llega un momento en donde estoy sacando el resultado de unas fechas y siempre me toma el primer dato y me repite el mismo resultado por los 100 datos que traigo.  Tengo el siguiente código

```
For i = 0 To Dt.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim resultado = getTiempo(System.Convert.ToDateTime(Dt.Rows(0).Item("FECHA_1")), System.Convert.ToDateTime(Dt.Rows(0).Item("FECHA_2")))

        Dim fl = New Tabla

        Dim col = New Tabla
        col.Text = Convert.ToString(i)
        fl.Cells.Add(col)

        Dim colNombre = New Tabla
        colNombre.Text = Convert.ToString(Dt.Rows(i).Item("NOMBRE"))
        fl.Cells.Add(colNombre)

        Dim colFecha = New Tabla
        colFecha.Text = (Dt.Rows(i).Item("FECHA_1"))
        fl.Cells.Add(colFecha)

        Dim colFecha2 = New Tabla
        colFecha2.Text = i.ToString(resultado)
        fl.Cells.Add(colFecha2)


        Table1.Rows.Add(rw)
    Next
```

Hasta aqui me trae los datos como corresponde del id, nombre, fecha_1, pero cuando quiero obtener el dato de la variable "resultado", siempre asigna el primer valor que es 10 minutos y me repite los 10 minutos en los 100 registros.  Yo se que mi problema esta aquí

```
Dim colFecha2 = New Tabla
        colFecha2.Text = i.ToString(resultado)
        fl.Cells.Add(colFecha2)
```

Por que no se como manejar el ciclo como corresponde.

Ayuda porfis
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en la primera instrucción dentro del bucle for. Estás trabajando con la fila 0 por lo que siempre utilizas los datos de dicha fila. En su lugar deberías emplear la variable i para indicar la fila.

```
Dim resultado = getTiempo(System.Convert.ToDateTime(Dt.Rows(0).Item("FECHA_1")), System.Convert.ToDateTime(Dt.Rows(0).Item("FECHA_2")))
```

Debería ser:

```
Dim resultado = getTiempo(System.Convert.ToDateTime(Dt.Rows(i).Item("FECHA_1")), System.Convert.ToDateTime(Dt.Rows(i).Item("FECHA_2")))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me había equivocado y era como tu decías, no estaba iniciando la variable i.